# Determine weather user liked a photo or not. Facebook Graph API v2.2

Tags: javascript, facebook-like, facebook-fql, facebook-graph-api-v2.2

I am working on Facebook application (JS sdk), In this app user can post like/comment on a photo. For this activity, It is showing a like button at bottom of photo. But if user already liked particular photo then we don't show like button there. For this we need to know weather user already liked the photo or not. It is possible to know this using FQL

```
 SELECT object_id,like_info,comment_info FROM photo WHERE object_id=343907262480651
```

And it returns a boolean flag  *data["like_info"]["user_likes"]*

I am migrating my code from graph api v1.0 to v2.2. So FQL will is longer available.

I want solution in graph API 2.2 similar to *user_likes* flag. I searched a lot for this, but not getting what exactly i want. Is there any alternative way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To get the likes for an object, you make call to

```
/{object-id}/likes
```

If you want the total number as a field, you need to set the field `summary=true`

Comment: I am able to get likes and like count. My question is how to know, "User has already liked the post or not ?"

Comment: I am also looking for a solution for this case. facebook picture page has a form like "facebook.com/fbid=123....." if use fbid as object-id i get error message. is there any way to check via facebook url?

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to accomplish the exact thing. So far, I couldn't find any end point that will readily tell you whether the user has already liked the post or not. But one work around is to call the /{object-id}/likes end point that will return you something like below:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "808004209267865", 
      "name": "Kailey Nicole"
    }, 
    {
      "id": "10204107012455593", 
      "name": "Brenda S. Coffelt"
    }
  ], 
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "OTU1NzQ4ODQxMTIyNDEz", 
      "after": "MTAyMDQxMDcwMTI0NTU1OTM="
    }, 
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/10151929326420059/likes?pretty=0&limit=25&after=MTAyMDQxMDcwMTI0NTU1OTM="
  }
}
```

You can then easily look for the user id in this JSON array. If it exists that means the user likes the page otherwise not. However keep in mind that there can be pagination (in case of lot of likes), so you'd really have to keep using the next URL to exhaust all likes data.